# Отбор последнего файла в каталоге назначения определенного формата

Tags: powershell

Есть скрипт на powershell, который из одного каталога выбирает последний там файл (а именно бэкап базы данных) копирует его на локальный диск (так-как бэкап находиться на другой машине в сети) и восстанавливает бэкап в тестовую базу. Все хорошо работает но есть один момент, если каким то образом в папку источник попадает файл отличный от бэкапа и он оказывается последним то скрипт берет и копирует его. В целом все логично что хотел то получил, но мне бы хотелось что бы скрипт отбирал последний только среди бэкапов то есть файлов с расширением *.bak
Вот пример самого скрипта.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param([string]  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $SqlServer=$null,      # SQL Сервер для которого будет исполняться скрипт
                    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $SqlBaseConnect=$null, # База данных к которой будем подклюдчаться       
                    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $SqlBaseRestore=$null, # База данных для которой будет исполняться скрипт
                    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $SqlLogin=$null,       # Логин базы данных
                    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $SqlPassw=$null,       # Пароль базы данных
                    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $destination=$null,    # Каталог назначения
                    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $DiskSource=$null,     # Диск источника
                    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $CatalogSource=$null)  # Каталог источника




#Запуск таймера
  $watch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
  $watch.Start() 

#Лог скрипта
  $LogF="RestoreBackupLog.txt"
  if (Test-Path $LogF) {Clear-Content $LogF}
       Add-Content -Path $LogF -Value   "Starting ..." 


# Переприсваиваем переменную источника к виду Путь источника
  $Source=$DiskSource+$CatalogSource

# Проверяем существует ли источник
  $TestPasth = Test-Path $Source
    if ($TestPasth -eq "True") {
                            # Выбираем самый новый файл на источнике.
                              $FileCopy = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ErrVarFile | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1

                       }
    else {Write-Host Указаный путь не существует
          exit}

# Копируем выбраный фаил 
  Copy-Item -Path "$Source\$FileCopy" -Destination "$destination" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ErrVar | Out-Null
    $ErrVarStd=$?
    Add-Content -Path $LogF -Value $ErrVar

# Проверяем скопировался ли фаил, если да то запускам востановлние базы
  if ($ErrVarStd -eq "True") {
                            #Подключение к  SQL и выполнение запроса 
                              $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
                              $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SqlServer; Database=$SqlBaseConnect; User ID=$SqlLogin; Password=$SqlPassw;"
                              $SqlConnection.Open()

                              $SqlCmd = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()
                              $SqlCmd.CommandText =  "Restore database [$SqlBaseRestore]
                                                      FROM DISK = '$destination\$FileCopy'"
                              $objReader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
                              while ($objReader.read()) {
                              Write-Output $objReader.GetValue(0)
                                                        }
                                $objReader.close()
                            # Удаляем фаил бэкапа из каталога назначения после востановления  
                                Remove-Item $destination\$FileCopy 
                              } 
  else {Write-Host Не удалось скопировать фаил бэкапа
        exit }  


#Остановка таймера
  $watch.Stop() 
  $elapsedtime=$watch.Elapsed
  Write-Host Время выполнения $elapsedtime
  Add-Content -Path $LogF -Value "Время выполнения $elapsedtime"
```

Если меняешь строку к виду

```
$FileCopy = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Include *.bak -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ErrVarFile | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1
```

То скрипт перестает работать, так как переменная $FileCopy принимает вид полного пути до файла, но при этом даже если заменить строку

```
Copy-Item -Path "$Source\$FileCopy"
```

на

```
Copy-Item -Path "$FileCopy"
```

Скрипт в точке назначения создает папку вместо файла  ну и соответственно падает не найдя файл. Подскажите как можно отбирать именно файлы бэкапа из целевого каталога.

Comment: Перепишите копирование так `$FileCopy | Copy-Item -Destination "$destination" ...`, или так `Copy-Item -Path $FileCopy.FullName -Destination "$destination" ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле все решилось несколько иначе. На выходных почитав монуалы )))) а именно как работает комадлет Get-ChildItem оказалось что нужно просто использовать вместо параметра 
**-Include** параметр **-Filter** и все прекрасно работает. Все потому что в качестве значения параметра **-Include** должны быть указаны все элементы, включая директорию, в которой производится поиск. При использовании -Filter результаты отфильтровываются непосредственно в процессе получения данных (папок и файлов), а -Include и -Exclude применяются уже после того, как все данные получены. Вот собственно и решение.